# Script to pop up on screen when user is missing data on row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that multiple people access and use to input data across a row. On that same row in column H there is a check box that marks that row completed.

I’m looking for a way that a message box pops up on the screen warning the user to make sure they tick the box in column H before proceeding to the next row.

The trigger would ACTIVE when the check box is not ticked and they go to insert something in the row beneath it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you want to be extremely annoying when they try to proceed, lightly annoying, or  actually make it nearly impossible for them to proceed? Your current request will be between nearly impossible and extremely annoying. For example anytime they try to type anything an alert box will pop up which will basically force them to check that box to proceed, is that your desired behavior? It would be extremely helpful for you to provide a sample sheet with sample data and your desired behavior so I can give you a formula that will "just work".

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have provided here is one possible solution. Let's say you have data in column A,B and column C has a series of checkboxes: highlight columns A:C and add a conditional formatting to make the background color black and add the following custom formula. That should force them to realize they need to finish the row before moving onto the next row. If you add more details to your question I can add more details to my answer.

```
=row()>match(FALSE,$C:$C,0)
```

The reason I didn't give you a pop up is because that would allow them to enter data still but you would constantly be spammed with a pop up box which doesn't appear to be your intention. If you still insist on having an alert box you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You forgot to finish the row!");` in conjunction with an `onEdit()` function.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui